# Speech to ext conversion

Tags: python, audio, text

I am trying to covert audio file to text.I have seen many post on it.But nothing is working for me.Could you please suggest me pythonic way to covert speech to text.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a pretty big question, but my best suggestion to you is to go with something like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygsr

```
from pygsr import Pygsr

speech = Pygsr()
speech.record(3) # durationin seconds (3)
phrase, complete_response =speech.speech_to_text('en_US') # select the language
print phrase
```

Edit1: If its an audio file you could open a google voice account, call yourself, play the audio file to leave as a voicemail. Google converts all your messages to text so it's essentially a free transcription service.